# Changing w2ui cell format

Tags: javascript, jquery, w2ui

I am trying to change background of one specific cell to geen in w2ui but the code doesn't work. I tried to search throu docs, demos and comments on the style property but didn't find anything helpful.

```
this.record.w2ui.style[2].background = "green";
```

"2" is the third column cell which background I want to change. Can anyone please give me the right syntax?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the local data just add the style property inside the record

Answer (score 0):

#for grid table#
`{ field : 'amount',
    caption : '<div style="text-align: center">Amount</div> ',
    render : 'int',
    style: 'background-color:green;'
    options : {min : 0, max : 999999999}
    }`